# Lotus Notes: NotesSQL Restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Does anybody know the restrictions of the **NotesSQL API** (Domino ODBC API)?
E.g. can I read mail **attachments** with this API?
Or should the **domino.dll** the prefered way to access **NSF files** (in the **.NET World**)?

Answer (score 1):

The NotesSQL API uses views to create its pseudo-tables. As an attachment is stored as an RTF field and RTF-fields can't be displayed in views, I think this is not possible.

I'm not completely up-to-date, my last experience with NotesSQL was with 6.5. But back then it was not very stable when querying large datasets so we dropped it quite fast for production use.